# What highpass filter is implemented in Audacity?

Tags: filter-design, filtering, audio-processing, highpass-filter

When I selected highpass filter effect in **Audacity** (an open-source audio editor), it lets me choose the cutoff frequency and the roll-off but it doesn't specify which filter type is used (IIR Butterworth, IIR Chebyshev or FIR types etc.).

Do you know which highpass filter is implemented in Audacity's highpass filter?
My guess is that if the filter is IIR then it is Butterworth, which needs only order (affecting roll-off) and cutoff frequency as parameters.

See this manual entry: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/high_pass_filter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly Butterworth.

1. Very standard filter for audio
2. It has a slope of 6dB/octave per order
3. No passband or stop band ripple.

2. and 3) would be difficult to do with an FIR filter especially for low frequencies and Chebyshev(s) and elliptic IIR filters have ripples.

Comment: And a [source code search](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/search?q=Biquad%3A%3ACalc) reveals internal support for Butterworth, Chebychev types 1 and 2 filters, all implemented as biquad structures.